# How to fix Logitech Unifying receiver not being detected by Windows

Tags: windows, logitech-mouse, wireless-mouse, logitech-unifying-receiver

I had the following symptoms: A new Logitech Wireless Mouse with a Unifying Receiver Dongle would not work.
The Task Manager would report an undetected Device in the „USB-Controller“ section.
Uninstalling that device or using different USB-ports would not work.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this sequence:

1. Uninstall the device from the Device manager.
2. Install the latest Logitech SetPoint Software from their website.
3. Detach *all* other Logitech Mice from the system.
4. Quit the SetPoint Application (right-click on the logo in the system tray)
5. Start SetPoint (Start -> Logitech -> Mouse & Keyboard Settings) with **right click -> Start as Administrator**)
6. **Now**, insert the Unifying receiver. The driver will automatically be installed.